# Do I need to drop a foreign key on one table to delete a row on another using oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have two tables

```
Parent table

(account_number     varchar(15)    not null,

branch_name        varchar(50)    not null,

balance         number not null,

primary key(account_number));





Child table

account_number     varchar(15)    not null,

foreign key(account_number) references parent table(account_number));
```

I am trying this:

```
DELETE FROM parent table

WHERE balances > 1000;
```

I am deleting accounts by balances on the parent but I get an error message about the child relationship.

My assumption is a DELETE CASCADE has to be added to the foreign key in the child table.  All the documentation shows how to alter the table when the constraint is named. I do not have that situation.  Is there a way to do it, or do I have to specify the cascade in the delete statement I am writing?

Answer (score 0):

Every constraint in Oracle has a name.  If a name isn't specified when the constraint is created, Oracle will autogenerate a name for the constraint.  If you don't know what the name of a  constraint is, try running a SQL statement that violates the constraint and reading the constraint name from the error message:

```
SQL> delete from parent where account_number = 1234;
delete from parent where account_number = 1234
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02292: integrity constraint (LUKE.SYS_C007357) violated - child record
found
```

In this case the name of the constraint is `SYS_C007357`.

If that doesn't work, you can query the data dictionary view `user_constraints`:

```
SQL> select constraint_name from user_constraints where table_name = 'CHILD' and constraint_type = 'R';

CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------
SYS_C007357
```

As far as I can tell, you can't modify a foreign key constraint to enable `ON DELETE CASCADE`.  Instead you must drop the constraint and recreate it.

I don't believe you can apply the `CASCADE` option to a `DELETE` statement either, but you can delete the child rows before deleting from the parent:

```
DELETE FROM child
 WHERE account_number IN (SELECT account_number FROM parent WHERE balance > 1000);

DELETE FROM parent
 WHERE balance > 1000;
```

However, I don't know how many other tables you have with foreign key constraints referencing your parent table, nor in how many places you are deleting from the parent table, so I can't say how much work it would be to use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can set DELETE CASCADE
see more info here  [FOREIGN KEYS WITH CASCADE DELETE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php)

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
  column1 datatype null/not null,
  column2 datatype null/not null,
  ...

  CONSTRAINT fk_column
     FOREIGN KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n)
     REFERENCES parent_table (column1, column2, ... column_n)
     ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

for example

```
CREATE TABLE supplier
( supplier_id numeric(10) not null,
  supplier_name varchar2(50) not null,
  contact_name varchar2(50),
  CONSTRAINT supplier_pk PRIMARY KEY (supplier_id)
);

CREATE TABLE products
( product_id numeric(10) not null,
  supplier_id numeric(10) not null,
  CONSTRAINT fk_supplier
    FOREIGN KEY (supplier_id)
    REFERENCES supplier(supplier_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```